# Инициализация массива сhar'ов

Tags: c++, массивы, литерал

```
const char k[3]={1,2,3};
char v[3] = k;
char d[] = "kk";  // const char[3]kk но еще это и константный литерал
```

Не очень понимаю, почему возможно инициализировать массив константным литералом, который также является массивом, а обычный массив нет. Понимаю, что должно быть посимвольное копирование в случае обычного массива,но почему работает во втором случае?

Comment: Компилятор для вас делает копию в массив. Сам литерал при этом не сохраняется.

Comment: Видимо просто не слишком удачная диагностика ошибки -- `error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer` / imho компилятор на самом деле не понимает неоднозначность оператора `char v[3] = k;`,  т.е. вы хотите инициализировать `v[]` содержимым `k[]` или его адресом (трактовка массива как указателя). / А вот так -- `char v[3] = {k[0], k[1], k[2]};` можно записать

Comment: @avp Если указателем, то не должно ли было быть `char *v = k;`? Я `C` не очень знаю, извините, если глупость написал )

Comment: @CrazyElf да, так тоже можно написать, тк по имени массива можно получить адрес 1-го элемента, то есть просто инициализируем адресом

Comment: транслитерация character вообще-то ˈkerəktər

Comment: @PavelGridin да, но это устоявшаяся в поколениях традиция обзывать символы и персонажей (игр) смесью французского с нижебостонским:  "чарами" )

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, да понятно, аш файл, диск цэ

Comment: @PavelGridin какой-такой цэ, у меня только рут и маунт! Но да, отучить их бывает невозможно, особенно когда еще советское поколение те же термины использует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно еще и так

```
const char d[3] = "kk";       // низя без const
char d2[3] = {'k','k','\0'};  // а этот массив можно менять
```

Это отдельные случаи. Литерал и список инициализации не являются массивами, это результаты этих выражений могут являться массивами. Проблема с

```
const char k[3]={1,2,3};
char v[3] = k;
```

в том, что с легкой руки г-на Кёнига и ради совместимости с Си, результат выражения `k` - это *prvalue* с типом `const char*`. Оно должно являться таковым, *иначе стандартное определение оператора* `[]` *в выражении* `k[2]` *не будет работать* - он требует того, чтобы один аргумент был prvalue, а другой - приводимым к значению, которое можно сложить с ним, т.е. это `*(k + 2)`<sup>[1]</sup>. `const char*` не совместим с `char[3]` и размер массива уже не известен.

Выходом из ситуации является использование агрегатной инициализации:

```
   struct Ar {
      char data[3];
   };
   Ar v1 = {"kk"};
   Ar v2 = v1;
```

Если сделать класс `Ar` шаблоном, мы получим прототип стандартного класса `std::array`:

```
   std::array<char, 10> v1 = {"kk"};
   auto v2 = v1;
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> А в результате `2[k]` - тоже легальное выражение.